# How to center align divs inside the parent container?

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

There is an issue with the first three divs which contains other elements in it.
If I remove them, then it is working fine but not otherwise.
[See Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgcvd.png)

```css
.results{
  text-align: center;
}
.result-box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="results">
    <div class="result-box"><p>Hello</p><p>World</p></div>
    <div class="result-box"><p>Nothing</p></div>
    <div class="result-box"><p>Everything</p></div>
    <div class="result-box"></div>
    <div class="result-box"></div>
    <div class="result-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `flexbox` to achieve it

Answer (score 2):

best solution for collect divs inside a container is using
[flex (display:flex)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [gird (display:gird)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) witch grid is not working correctly in old browser ( internet explorer)

but if you don't like to use these methods
here is a tricky way

```css
.results{
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
.result-box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="results">
    <div class="result-box"><p>Hello</p><p>World</p></div>
    <div class="result-box"><p>Nothing</p></div>
    <div class="result-box"><p>Everything</p></div>
    <div class="result-box"></div>
    <div class="result-box"></div>
    <div class="result-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the below snippet

```css
.results{
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.result-box{
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="results">
    <div class="result-box"><p>Hello</p><p>World</p></div>
    <div class="result-box"><p>Nothing</p></div>
    <div class="result-box"><p>Everything</p></div>
    <div class="result-box"></div>
    <div class="result-box"></div>
    <div class="result-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to shrink the size of result-box. I want it that to be on the next line when the width of window reduces. That's why I was not using flex property.